# Multi-dimensional JOINs with ActiveRecord and Sinatra

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord, sinatra, inner-join

I've recently broken out a single table into three separate tables and now am having trouble combining them into a list.

I have a Venue
 - has many Orders
  - has many Items

In an attempt to list all the orders and accompanying information from a Venue:

app.rb

```
get "/:venue/orders" do
  @venue = Venue.find_by_handle(params[:venue])
  @orders = Order.joins(:venue).where(:venues => {:handle => @venue.handle})
  @items = Item.joins(:order).where(:orders => {:id => @orders.id})
  erb :"venue/index"
end
```

venue/index.erb

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  <h3>Order <%= order.id %></h3>
  <h4><%= @customer.email %></h4>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <h5><%= item.quantity %> x <%= item.item %></h5>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

models.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :customer

  has_many :items

  validates :venue_id, presence: true
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order

  validates :order_id, :presence => true
  validates :quantity, :presence => true
  validates :item, :presence => true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders

  validates :email, :presence => true
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :customers, :through => :orders
  has_many :orders

  validates :name, :presence => true
  validates :handle, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
end
```

I receive a NoMethodError for 'id' and understand because i'm not looking at a specific order. How do I go about querying for the necessary items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
@venue = Venue.includes({:orders => [:customer, :items]}).find_by_handle(params[:venue])
```

Then, in your view:

```
<% @venue.orders.each do |order| %>
  <h3>Order <%= order.id %></h3>
  <h4><%= order.customer.email %></h4>
  <% order.items.each do |item| %>
    <h5><%= item.quantity %> x <%= item.item %></h5>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get "undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass." I'm thinking this has something to do with my models? I'll update the question with them.

Comment: I guess you also need to retrieve the customer then. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Now i'm getting "Association named 'items' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"

Comment: Sorry, try switching :items and :orders around, edited my answer as well.

Comment: I tried that, then I get the "undefined method 'klass' for nil:NilClass". I'm thinking my model associations are messed up, but aren't sure how to reformat them.

Comment: can you actually create venues and associate orders and items to them without getting an error?

Comment: Talk about making dozens of mistakes! I had pluralized 'customer' not realizing that an order doesn't has_many 'customers', but has only one. Once that clicked, I then realized my local database had a few records missing that were giving me my error of 'undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass'

Comment: Thanks a ton for your patience and help!